# python get isoformat date time from time

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime

I have this string:

date_string = "2022-04-11 00:00:00.000000"

which I'm trying to convert to this format:

date = "2022-04-11T00:00:00.000Z"

Can anyone please help me with the same

i tried to do this but am getting Error like invalid format

```
datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M:%S%z")
```

Comment: Have you tried using `strptime` and then using `strftime`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes i did but am getting error's  like not a valid format

Comment: Do you want to know what you did wrong?

Comment: yeah i'm looking for that only @mkrieger1 can you please help

Comment: Then you have to show what you did.

Comment: @mkrieger1
first i converted string to datetime 
datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)
then i'm trying to convert it to 
datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M:%S%z")

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: please have another look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior): parsing directive has to match the input ("%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M:%S%z" doesn't in your example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 2):

There's a library known as dateutil.
With the help of that, we parse the string into date format and then we convert it into the isoformat.

`import dateutil.parser as parser`

`date_string = "2022-04-11 00:00:00.000000"`

`date = parser.parse(date_string)`

`print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))`

The output would be
`2022-04-11T00:00:00Z`

Comment: Hi Thank for the response but how to you add that missing Z in the end i tried to do the same but it's giving same error invalid format

Comment: You can use this to add Z at the end of your date                                 print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))